# What is a "terrorist jacket"?

Tags: doomsday-book, connie-willis

In Connie Willis' *[Doomsday Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Book_%28novel%29)*, American archaeologist Lupe Montoya is described as wearing a "terrorist jacket" in several places:

> Kivrin’s tutor Latimer, looking older and even more infirm than usual,
>   was standing next to one of the trunks. Montoya was standing over by
>   the console wearing jeans and a terrorist jacket and looking
>   impatiently at the digital on her wrist. Badri was sitting in front of
>   the console, typing something in and frowning at the display screens.

and

> “Well, great,” she said, jamming her papers angrily into the pockets
>   of her terrorist jacket. “The whole village will have washed away
>   while I’m stuck here.” She stomped out.

and

> Montoya was covered in mud, too. She was wearing her terrorist jacket
>   and thigh-high fisherman’s waders like Basingame, wherever he was,
>   might be wearing, and they were wet and filthy.

I've tried looking up "terrorist jacket", but I'm only seeing things branded "terror" and a few references to vests that suicide bombers wear. Is this an actual item of clothing, or is it some sort of future piece of fashion that we're supposed to imagine? As you can see, there's not much context to go on in figuring out what it might look like.

Comment: My first thought was that it was an editor's mis-translation of "bomber jacket"

Comment: She's also wearing a "terrorist shirt" a few pages later

Comment: The spanish translation refers to "una chaqueta de terrorista", literally a 'bomber' jacket. Also, they've made the character male for some reason.

Comment: @DVK - I reluctantly agree. It doesn't seem to be plot-relevant.

Comment: ELL seems like an odd suggestion, even if it's not on-topic here. Personally I don't see a problem with having questions asking about references/terms the reader didn't understand in works that are science fiction. There's at least [some](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/in-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-what-are-rushes) precedent for it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - the problem isn't that it's offtopic here as much as that ELL would offer deeper pool of expertise for the answer.

Comment: @DVK It's definitely not an ELL question, since I'm a native English speaker. My question is whether it's either 1.) a science fiction term in general I'm not familiar with, 2.) invented for this specific work of science fiction or 3.) just happens to be something real.

Comment: @Paul - I think that ELL - while not perfect - is as close as you get to translation issues - and I agree with Richard that this most likely is originating with "bomber jacket".

Comment: I'm amenable to moving this over to English Language and Usage if it's pretty clear this isn't some reference to some weird thing Robert Heinlein wrote or whatever. I can't imagine it would be a translation issue - Connie Willis is American (though the book seems to be lightly "translated" into a future version of BrE).

Comment: Isn't the book originally published in English? Would translation issues be plausible in that case?

Comment: I think this might be a case of an imaginative future translation. If @Paul is right and there are other linguistic quirks explainable by the book being written in the language of the late 21st C, then this might be one of them - i.e. suggesting that late 21st C people have lost the difference between the words 'bomber' as in jacket and 'bomber' as in terrorist.

Comment: I tried migrating this question to [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302557) and it seems to me like it's not a real term. The more I think about it, the more I think it should be re-opened here. It's clear that the term is made up for the book.

Comment: @Paul - More likely it's an idiosyncratic turn of phrase from the author. In context I think she just means a [worn jacket](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/43/b6/e4/43b6e4298ce4d75592ff3cfacf6a6af8.jpg), like a terrorist might wear.

Comment: Oh, I think there's idio-something going on. If that Spanish translation were referring to the real garment and not something made up, it would be "...de bombardero" or "...de aviador".

Comment: @Richard It seems odd to make up a fanciful turn of phrase and exclusively use that to refer to the item in question. I think we agree on what the jacket actually is, though, because I'm most convinced by the idea that she was imagining the evolution of the phrase of "bomber jacket" to "terrorist jacket". If she ever does a public Q and A or AMA style thing I'm going to try and ask.

Comment: @T.J.L. - Ah, but I rather suspect you'll find that the translated version probably hasn't been subjected to the same scrutiny as, say, a Harry Potter book. The author will likely have had little or no involvement at all, relying on the translator and translator's editor to ensure that the book remains true to the original

Comment: I don't know what a terrorist jacket means, but I wouldn't trust one!

Comment: This book appeared in 1992. At the time Yassar Arafat was still a public figure, and affected military jackets (with lots of pockets) and was considered by many to be a terrorist ... would this be a possible connection?

Comment: A photographer's jacket has many pockets and is often worn by journalists and other people who travel internationally in third world countries. I agree with those saying it simply is poetic license on the part of the author.